# Limit tab navigation to a UI Element

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, focus

I´m building a UWP app. I´m currently working making it more accessible  so I´m only using it with the keyboard and navigating with the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

Sometimes I show a UserControl with 2 buttons using all the screen, leaving the rest of the page elements at the background. But if I use tab to navigate to this 2 buttons, the focus quickly goes to the elements at the background and that´s what I´m trying to avoid.

I want tab to only focus on those 2 buttons from the user control I displayed.

I noticed that some framework elements like ContentDialog do this automatically, and I´d like the same behavior.

Any ideas on how can I limit the tab navigation inside a UserControl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you show the `UserControl`, you could trigger a modification on your layout by setting `IsTabStop` dependency property to *false* for the elements present in the background.

Either that or you can also disable the elements in the background, but that will also modify the appearance of the controls, something which might be undesired for your specific intentions.

- In case there's a variety of elements which need to have its
  `IsTabStop` set to false, instead of defining an identifier
  attribute with `x:Name` and having to refer each single one in
  code-behind, I would suggest to loop through a Layout `Children`
  dependency property and modify the controls properties this way.

### Update:

I had misunderstood your requirement completely. After re-reading, I understand what are your objectives, and those seem to be achievable based on the documentation!

Taking a look at [Tab Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/focus-navigation#tab-navigation) here and [Control Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-interactions#control-group) documentation, it is indicated that you can customize control navigation, by using the following properties of the API:

> `XYFocusKeyboardNavigation` enables arrow key navigation between
>   controls
>
> `TabFocusNavigation` indicates whether there are multiple tab
>   stops or single tab stop
>
> `FindFirstFocusableElement` and
>   `FindLastFocusableElement` sets focus on the first item with Home key
>   and the last item with End key

Taking a look into the template, we see the following `VisualState` defined for the `ContentDialog`:

```
<VisualState x:Name="DialogShowing">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Target="BackgroundElement.TabFocusNavigation" Value="Cycle" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

This visual state occurs when the dialog is shown and it sets the `TabFocusNavigation` dependency property to *Cycle* meaning that all the children will receive focus once and the tab navigation will loop while the property is set this way.

In the links above the documentation is awesome and there's a graphical representation for each possible value that can be set for the `TabFocusNavigation`.

The reason why your `UserControl` was not working as expected, is because it's navigation behavior follows the conventions for the *Local* scenario.

Comment: I would like to avoid that solution, as then I'd have to restore the IsTapStop original status for all that elements, and I want to avoid that complexity. The ContentDialog doesn't modify anything and avoid the focus from going out of the scope.

Comment: You could create a method which simply switches the state of those elements in the background and call it whenever the UserControl shows up/ is removed.
But I understand your intentions, but I dunno right now if it's possible to achieve this with a simpler approach.

Comment: Can you verify if it's possible to set XYFocusKeyboardNavigation property in the layout outside of the UserControl?

Comment: It's not possible in UWP to put that property, it's way more limited. But in some way they do it with the ContentDialog.

Comment: What about  TabFocusNavigation or TabNavigation? These two are my last guesses xD

Comment: Oops I think these two only set how the navigation cycle is done with the tab, and don't actually control whether something is focusable or not.

Comment: Yes it's quite tricky, if they would have open source all the controls, this would be easier to answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I had misunderstood what was exactly your intentions, and I think I have provided a better answer to your intentions.

Comment: Hi, using TabNavigation="Cycle" solved the problem. Thanks!